# Installing kubectl on Ubuntu 20.04 didn't create any .conf file inside /usr/kubernetes/

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

I am installing kubectl in Ubuntu 20.04 following the guide [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/) but it didn't create `/etc/kubernetes` folder for some reason. Then I tried this [guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/) , it now created a that folder, but only with `manifests` inside. There is no `.conf` file created. It will return this error if I ran `kubectl cluster-info`.

```
W0629 19:50:08.122990   83790 loader.go:221] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

Anyone knows the solution? Thanks

Comment: Please provide ```ls -la /etc/kubernetes``` output .

Answer (score 2):

First things first. Kubernetes and kubectl are different things. Installing kubectl is not supposed to create `/etc/kubernetes` folder or files there. The `kubectl` cli tool is only a client for a kubernetes cluster. If you already have a Kubernetes cluster then you can provide a `kubeconfig` to this cli tool. This will enable you to interact with the cluster.

Your second link is installing kubernetes cluster with `kubeadm` cli tool. This will create a cluster from ground up. If cluster creation is completed successfully then `kubeadm` tool will automatically create an `admin.conf` file for you. This file is also a `kubeconfig` file.